# mySQL set a varchar without the special characters

Tags: mysql

I use mySQL as a DBMS,
I have these rows in my table:

```
product_name | product_code | prod_type
prod1@00X    |  1           |    
@prod2@00X   |  2           | 
+prod3@@00X  |  3           |
```

I wanna set the prod_type = the product_name without the special characters.

```
=> prod_type

   prod100X
   prod200X
   prod300X
```

(I can have other special characters not only '@' and '+')

How can I do that?

Comment: So you have only @ and + or there may be other special char also ?

Comment: yes, I can have other special character

Comment: hmm this will be pretty difficult in a single query since the char could be any special char. Using replace function also will not work since you do not know what char to be replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:**

You can use the [REPLACE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) method to remove special characters in mysql, don't know if it's very efficient though. But it should work.

Like Below:

```
SELECT Replace(Replace(product_name,'@',''),'+','')  as prod_type
From Table1
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f12e0d/1)**

**Method 2:**

If you have All other Special Charcter then go with this ([Source](http://www.shayanderson.com/mysql/remove-invalid-non-ascii-characters-in-mysql-query-using-stored-function.htm))

```
-- ---------------------------- 
-- Function structure for `udf_cleanString` 
-- ---------------------------- 
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `udf_cleanString`; 
DELIMITER ;; 
CREATE FUNCTION `udf_cleanString`(`in_str` varchar(4096)) RETURNS varchar(4096) CHARSET utf8 
BEGIN    
      DECLARE out_str VARCHAR(4096) DEFAULT ''; 
      DECLARE c VARCHAR(4096) DEFAULT ''; 
      DECLARE pointer INT DEFAULT 1; 

      IF ISNULL(in_str) THEN 
            RETURN NULL; 
      ELSE 
            WHILE pointer <= LENGTH(in_str) DO 

                  SET c = MID(in_str, pointer, 1); 

                  IF ASCII(c) > 31 AND ASCII(c) < 127 THEN 
                        SET out_str = CONCAT(out_str, c); 
                  END IF; 

                  SET pointer = pointer + 1; 
            END WHILE; 
      END IF; 

      RETURN out_str; 
END 
;; 
DELIMITER ;
```

After that just call the function as follows:

```
SELECT product_name, udf_cleanString(product_name) AS 'product_Type' 
FROM table1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used the second method

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Replace(Replace(product_name,'@',''),'+','') 
From Table
```

in case other special characters try nested `Replace`

like this

```
 select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(product_name, '/', ''),'(',''),')',''),' ',''),'+',''),'-',''),'@','');
```

or try using `Regex`

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is,

1. Create a function to remove the special character, you can find how from the [refernece](http://tricks.ekollege.com/codeigniter/mysql-function-to-remove-special-characters-or-mysql-clean-string-function/)
2. use the query `Update YourTable  set prod_type = YourFunction(product_name )`